# How to change the context name in the uri

Tags: spring, maven, jakarta-ee

I have given my web.xml file and also my pom.xml but i am not able to change my Uri when my projects first starts. I am getting this in my URI http://localhost:8080/orgchart/ while my project name is bepolite and I want it to show http://localhost:8080/bepolite/  when my project starts. below is my pom.xml

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mob</groupId>
    <artifactId>bepolite</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>bpolite Maven Webapp</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <slf4j-api.version>1.7.5</slf4j-api.version>
        <slf4j-log4j.adapter.version>1.7.5</slf4j-log4j.adapter.version>

        <!-- maven settings -->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${maven.compiler.source}</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.debug>true</maven.compiler.debug>

        <!-- maven plugins versions -->
        <maven-clean-plugin.version>2.4.1</maven-clean-plugin.version>
        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>2.3.2</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
        <maven-resources-plugin.version>2.4.3</maven-resources-plugin.version>
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>2.2</maven-jar-plugin.version>
        <maven-release-plugin.version>2.3.1</maven-release-plugin.version>
        <maven-enforcer-plugin.version>1.0.1</maven-enforcer-plugin.version>
        <maven-gwt-plugin.version>2.4.0</maven-gwt-plugin.version>
        <maven-sql-plugin.version>1.5</maven-sql-plugin.version>
        <maven-war-plugin.version>2.2</maven-war-plugin.version>
        <maven-surefire-plugin.version>2.9</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
        <maven-failsafe-plugin.version>2.9</maven-failsafe-plugin.version>
        <maven-antrun-plugin.version>1.7</maven-antrun-plugin.version>
        <maven-release-plugin.version>2.3.2</maven-release-plugin.version>
        <maven-scm-plugin.version>1.7</maven-scm-plugin.version>

        <spring.version>4.1.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.security.version>3.1.3.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
        <spring-data-jpa.version>1.2.0.RELEASE</spring-data-jpa.version>
        <spring.batch.version>2.1.9.RELEASE</spring.batch.version>

        <javassist.version>3.12.0.GA</javassist.version>
        <mysql-connector-java.version>5.1.18</mysql-connector-java.version>

        <hibernate.version>4.1.4.Final</hibernate.version>
        <hibernate-tools.version>3.2.4.GA</hibernate-tools.version>
        <hibernate-validator.version>4.0.2.GA</hibernate-validator.version>
        <hibernate-jpa-2.0-api.version>1.0.0.Final</hibernate-jpa-2.0-api.version>

        <servlet-api.version>2.5</servlet-api.version>

        <urlrewritefilter.version>3.2.0</urlrewritefilter.version>

        <commons-collections.version>3.2.1</commons-collections.version>
        <commons-fileupload.version>1.2.2</commons-fileupload.version>
        <commons-io.version>2.3</commons-io.version>
        <commons-collections.version>3.2.1</commons-collections.version>
        <commons-lang.version>2.1</commons-lang.version>
        <commons-lang3.version>3.0.1</commons-lang3.version>

        <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>

        <c3p0.version>0.9.1.2</c3p0.version>
        <validation-api.version>1.0.0.GA</validation-api.version>
        <aspectjweaver.version>1.6.8</aspectjweaver.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.6.2</slf4j.version>
        <janino.version>2.5.16</janino.version>

        <jclouds.version>1.7.1</jclouds.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- =============== Spring ===================== -->
        <dependency>

            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>

            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>

            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Googleoauth -->



        <!-- spring security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectjweaver.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- spring-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-data-jpa.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Hibernate Libraries -->
        <!-- hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-tools</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-tools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-validator.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-jpa-2.0-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- javassist - needed because hibernate failed to declare it as dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>${javassist.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- C3P0 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>${c3p0.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>${validation-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL JDBC driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql-connector-java.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- servlet API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servlet-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Image upload -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-fileupload.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-io.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!--Cache Libraries -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jsr107cache</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr107cache</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Commons Libraries -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>


        <!-- commons lang -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-lang.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- commons lang 3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-lang3.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- commons collections 3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-collections.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- validation api -->
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>javax.validation</groupId> <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId> 
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version> </dependency> -->


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
            <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
            <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-http-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.1-beta</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.1-beta</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>v2-rev29-1.13.2-beta</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20090211</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>google-api-services</id>
            <url>http://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/mavenrepo</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <build>

        <outputDirectory>target/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
        <resources>

            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources-filtered</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/java</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </testResource>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>


        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
         <plugin>
              <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
              <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>0.3.7</version>
              <configuration>
                <appName>glacial-fjord-5506</appName>
                <processTypes>
     <web>java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* Main</web>
  </processTypes>
              </configuration>
            </plugin>

                <!-- setup version information -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <warName>bepolite</warName>
                        <packagingExcludes> WEB-INF/classes/staples.properties,
                            WEB-INF/classes/staples-uat.properties,
                            WEB-INF/classes/configuration.properties,
                            WEB-INF/classes/configuration-uat.properties
                        </packagingExcludes>
                        <webResources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/version</directory>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                                <targetPath>version</targetPath>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>**/*.txt</include>
                                </includes>
                            </resource>
                        </webResources>
                    </configuration>

                </plugin>



                <!-- Copy static web files before executing gwt:run -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>compile</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <outputDirectory>target/www</outputDirectory>
                                <resources>
                                    <resource>
                                        <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                                    </resource>
                                </resources>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

                <!-- Delete gwt generated stuff -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <filesets>
                            <fileset>
                                <directory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes</directory>
                            </fileset>
                            <fileset>
                                <directory>tomcat</directory>
                            </fileset>
                            <fileset>
                                <directory>www-test</directory>
                            </fileset>
                        </filesets>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

</project>
```

here is my web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml, /WEB-INF/onramp-daos.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 1):

2 things you can try:

1) Build your project with clean goal (mvn clean ....)

2) Define the finalName property under build

```
<build>
        <finalName>bepolite</finalName>
        <outputDirectory>target/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
        ...
```